# OpenGL template changes Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates, opengl-es

I'm currently attempting to learn how to program in OpenGL in iOS. Turns out the book that I'm reading is made for Xcode 3 (Learning iOS Game Programming) and there's a huge leap in integrating Open GL between Xcode v3 and v4.5 with getting rid of the separation of OpenGL v1 and v2, the OpenGL library and getting rid of the old template. I think it would really help me get a starting foot if I could look at the original OpenGL template (the one with the 2D square moving up and down) translated over to the new standard OpenGL template, instead of seeing the 3 dimensional squares, so I can see what's translated to what. I have no idea why they changed the view (to show off possibilities?) but it makes it extremely hard to cross reference to know what should go where and what's what compared to the older template. Does anyone know a good way to tackle this or better yet, has the old template been translated?

Answer (score 0):

The template that is included in xcode 4.5 uses openGL es 2. It shows 2 approaches. The first one is by using OpenGL ES 2.0 natively, shaders and everything that people are used to. The other is by using the special apple framework (GLKit). This one is made to ease the leap between OpenGL 1 and 2. (The transition between fixed and programable pipeline). My suggestion is to change completely your sources. Focus completely on OpenGL ES 2.0 by using other internet sources.

This link here explains the basics using the new template:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

Comment: I've already looked at this specific site a few times. It's more so that I actually enjoy the book I'm currently reading and would like to know the programming differences between OpenGL v1 and v2. The book that I have is probably one of the VERY few game programming books for OpenGL in iOS that is very clearly explained. I don't really want to pull away from it to just target OpenGL 2.0 and look up countless more 'bad' tutorials on game programming in OpenGL ES for iOS. Would you really recommend going to a different book? Sadly, this would also make the minor purchase of that book a waste ..

Comment: Mind you, I do plan on moving on to just purely OpenGL ES v2 (as is everyone). It's simply knowing the foundation, migration, and basics. I'd like to know how to create a simple game with the simple concepts (as this book explains) before diving into the shader language.

Comment: The thing is, OpenGL ES 1 and es 2 are COMPLETELY different. The first one is easier indeed but all new apple devices support version 2. And you can do much more with it. If you do not already know 1, then there is much more to gain to just focus on v2.0. Read this as an intro to opengl es 2.0 http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.jp/2010/10/opengl-es-20-for-ios-chapter-1.html

Comment: Well this is what you can do. Read your book the theory behind the games, how screen refreshing works, interactions etc etc. But for programming look for a good OpenGL 2 source, because they are really different. OpenGL 1 allows you to move a camera, create some lightning points, simple effects. It uses functions already made, in 2.0 you have to make everything manually.

Comment: ALTERNATIVELY, there are some frameworks that simplify this, like Cocos2D.

Comment: I was going to completely avoid Cocoas 2D. I want to learn what will last and carry over. I see Cocos2D being a temporary unflexible language. It's easy to pick up and use... but when it's gone the knowledge could be useless while Open GL has been a standard forever. I guess I will just read my book for the theory (which is kind of annoying without practice). I do have a few books on OpenGL 2.0 with iOS and I have the book for the site you referenced above. I honestly just wish there was a good 2D GAME programming book for OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS. Any references?

Comment: I mean, I have Learning OpenGL ES for iOS: A Hands On Guide to Modern 3D Graphics Programming which will help me learn OpenGL ES 2.0. But... I'm not sure how hard OpenGL ES 2.0 will be to use to create a 2D game compared to using say... Quartz 2D. Which would be better and are there any good Quartz 2D iOS game development books out there? Tutorials?